# Авторизация на сайте c++/php

Tags: php, c++, post, auth

Мне нужно проверить логин и пароль на сервере, и отправить ответ(верный или нет) на пк. Для этих целей решил использовать "cpp-httplib". Как мне получить ответ с сервера? За помощь - заранее спасибо!

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $login = filter_var(trim($_POST['login']), FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $pass = filter_var(trim($_POST['pass']), FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

    $pass = md5($pass."fasdf");

    $mysql = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', 'root', 'users');

    $result = $mysql->query("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `login` = '$login' AND `pass` = '$pass'");
    $user = $result->fetch_assoc();
    if(empty($user) or count($user) == 0) {
        $_SESSION['message'] = 'Неверный логин или пароль!';
        header('Location: auth.php');
        exit();
    }


    $_SESSION['user'] = [
        "id" => $user['id'],
        "login" => $user['login'],
        "email" => $user['email'],
        "group" => $user['group'],
        "regdate" => $user['regdate']
    ];
    
    $mysql->close();

    header('Location: account.php');
?>
```

```
#include <iostream>
#include "httplib.h"

int main()
{
    httplib::Client cli("http://localhost");
    httplib::Params params{
        { "login", "1" },
        { "pass", "1" }
    };
    auto res = cli.Post("/auth_check.php", params);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Я конечно C++, не знаю но дам один вопрос
можно на C++ получить JSON дата и проверит что на JSON файлу,
если да скажите напишу код как сделать на PHP

Comment: Ну вот же полученный ответ `auto res`.

Comment: res выдаёт "1" в любом случае, не в зависимости от того верный ли пароль или логин, даже если я укажу несуществующий .php файл он выдаст "1". Главное чтобы соединение с localhost было, иначе "0" напишет.

Comment: Изучайте исходный код, для каждого запроса есть его объект (Request), и объект ответа (Response). У ответа есть метод получения или проверки заголовка на существование. В документации есть пример получения заголовка через get_header_value.